# Lightning Community Builder deployment

Tags: lightning, lightning-community

HI I have Community Builder with 20 Plus pages, Now I have to deploy it to another sandboxes, Not able to add it change sets. Is it possible to deploy my existing community builder along with my pages in to higher environments.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can not move custom community pages directly via network/site by using change set deployment model.

you have to do below steps:

> 1. go to community builder=>Setting => Developer => Export A Page Tab
>
>    2. then choose what pages you want to move from `select a page to export` dropdown.
>    3. if you search with `lightning community pages` word in lightning experience`quick find` 'll shown all pages what ever you
>         exported in step 2
>    4. then create change set, and choose `Lightning page` metadata type then select pages what ever you want. then move those pages in to
>         target org

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot for your answer, Could you please let me know what are the pre and post deployment steps need to be done. Means in Target Org I have created Community with same name and Template as like source, and added Network , 2 Site.coms to the change sets, after deploying, Target Org throws error.

Comment: why 2 site.coms, only one site.com , other one is custom site. can you update/create new your question with exact issue with what you have done.